# Symfony and very slow ajax requests

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

I'm trying to do some ajax requests using symfony and I noticed that there is a huge difference in response time when I send a GET request to:

a) The most simple symfony controller method which just returns: Reponse("Hello")
[image: AJAX with symfony]
b) PHP file which pretty much does the same thing (echo "Hello")
[image: AJAX without symfony]
My app is really dependend on those response times and I want them to be as short as possible, so I just can't tolerate such a long waiting periods in case of symfony. Is there any way I can make it work faster? And yes, I was testing it in the PROD enviroment.

Comment: Symfony will always be slower than a simple PHP file, because it instanciate a lot of classes and does some work. Considerate HTTP caching if it can help you. http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html

Comment: I guess it won't be helpful in my case. I know it has to do some work, but as you can see the difference is huge and even the simpliest possible request can take almost one second. I was looking for something that could maybe help speeding up this loading process. If it's not possible I guess I'll have to consider using some other framework.

Comment: If you just need an `echo "hello"` its a waste of memory try to use a framework... Maybe you can do the same example doing a real example... working with databases, calculating data and returning a complex view... You will find a Framework is necessary.

Comment: It was just an example to show how much time symfony needs to  proceed the simplest GET request. Now considering that my database operations would even take 400 ms less thanks to Symfony (which they won't) it will still take longer to get the response, since loading the classes themselves takes 600ms. Also my database operations aren't that complex in this case. If there is nothing I can do about it and it will always take so much time to load even when the script is not doing much work then I guess symfony was a poor choice and I'll just use another framework for my project (like Yii maybe)

Comment: Complementing what @Pipe say, choosing a framework is justified by the saved work that the same functionality will take in simple php, with a reasonable response time.

Comment: @LeszekWiesner Maybe then you don't need a framework... Symfony is a very complete framework... By default all functionalities are loaded, you can disable some functionalities you will not use, to reduce loading times... do you use Security component? Forms? Twig? 
Or maybe you need a "micro framework" that allows simple tasks

Comment: Symfony has it's own microframework, http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-symfony-as-a-microframework